# Checkbox binding not working in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to change an isChecked value on my property, but the value is not changing. I've tried various things, but can't seem to crack it. Am I required to implement INotifyPropertyChanged when doing twoway binding? I'm new to this, so it's a bit confusing to me. I'm attempting to follow the MVVM pattern.

## XAML

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Servers}" Margin="8,30,10,68">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Select For Sync">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Tag="{Binding NodeName}" IsChecked="{Binding isChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="280" Header="Pad Name"  
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NodeName}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

## Server Class (Server.cs)

```
public class Server
{
    #region Server Properties
    public string NodeName{ get; set; }
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

## ViewModel Logic to Get Servers Checked

`List<Server> checkedRows = Servers.Where(s => s.isChecked).ToList();`

## How I Am Testing

```
        foreach(Server obj in Servers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Server: {obj.NodeName}\nChecked:{obj.isChecked.ToString()}");
        }
```

EDIT: The item source is defined in the viewmodel like so:

```
public ObservableCollection<Server> Servers { get; set; }
```

Comment: When you say "the value is not changing", are you saying that changes in the UI aren't reflected in the viewmodel? How are you using this DataTemplate? Can you show us that part?

Comment: The values in my object are not changing from true-> false and vice versa.

Comment: How are you using this DataTemplate? Can you show us that part?

Comment: I've updated the original post.

Comment: Looks good to me. When you populate the listview initially, if some of the `Server`s have `isChecked == true` at that point, do the UI checkboxes get checked correctly? Try this in the binding: `IsChecked="{Binding isChecked,PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"` (remove the other stuff you added, those are no-ops here), and see what you see in the Output pane in VS at runtime.

Comment: I've updated the OP again to show how I am testing this. I have a command linked to a button that prints the checked values of each object in the Servers list. The checkboxes do initialize as true/false if I throw in test data onload, so that's a good sign. Each time I click the button, it never changes the original "isChecked" value as I change it from the UI.

Comment: Slightly O/T, this will call ToString() for you, no need to do it explicitly: `$"{obj.isChecked}"`

Comment: Thanks, was wondering about that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146905/discussion-between-ryan-and-ed-plunkett).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this turns out to be a variation on the classic Double ViewModel Fake-Out:

```
<Window.Resources> 
    <Client:VMConvergence x:Key="convergenceVM" /> 
</Window.Resources> 

<Window.DataContext> 
    <Client:VMConvergence/> 
</Window.DataContext>

...

    <Button 
        x:Name="btnDeploy" 
        Content="Sync System Changes" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,208,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="366" 
        Command="{Binding simple.ConvergenceModel.simple, Source={StaticResource convergenceVM}}" 
        />

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Servers}" Margin="8,30,10,68">
        <!-- ... -->
```

Everything's fine, the bindings work perfectly, but OP was checking the values by invoking a command on a different instance of the viewmodel.

Easy fix: Get rid of the `convergenceVM` resource, and change the binding to let it use the inherited `DataContext` for its source:

```
        Command="{Binding simple.ConvergenceModel.simple}"
```

Answer (score -1):

You Should try using `RelativeSource`.

Like

```
<CheckBox Tag="{Binding NodeName}" IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.isChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GridViewCell,Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>
```

Comment: RelativeSource what?

Comment: `<CheckBox Tag="{Binding NodeName}" IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.isChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell,Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>`

Comment: There is no DataGridCell. This is a ListView. If you had tested OP's code, you would have found that there is no problem at all with the binding on `IsChecked`.

Comment: If your comment were part of a meaningful answer, you should put it *in your answer*, instead of hiding it in a comment.

Comment: My mistake it sould be `<CheckBox Tag="{Binding NodeName}" IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.isChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GridViewCell,Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>`

Comment: No. It should be exactly what OP had. I tested his code. That binding was correct. The problem was unrelated.